# kerberos error while getting initial ticket - kpasswd

Tags: kerberos, change-password

I get the following error while trying to change password using Kerberos kpasswd.

"Inappropriate  I/O control operation getting initial ticket".

Not a able to find appropriate reason/solution to fix this error. PLease advice.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late but came across this question with no replies, hence thought to reply, might be helpful to someone.

It seems that you got the first initialize your kerberos environment, In ADE same message comes up if "ade okinit" is not performed, I would suggest you to check if similar initialization needed before running your command. Hope it helps.

Thanks.